# What is the diffrence between {{ name }} and {{{ name }}} in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

What is the diffrence between {{ name }} and {{{ name }}} in Vue.js?

Is it for escaping special strings in HTML template or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{ name }}` interprets data as a plain text,to render Html you need to use `{{{name}}}`